# Writing user choice directly to Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, google-sheets

I'm using https://github.com/Iwark/react-native-spreadsheet to implement what I want.

The ultimate goal of my program to place the user `Choice` from the `data[]` array directly into my `Google Sheets` upon the user tapping on it.  But for now, I just want to see some change be made to my `Google Sheets`.  [image: this is the error I'm getting]

I feel like I'm really close to achieving this but I seem to be off somewhere.

Here's my `.js` file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { ScrollView, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import { logout } from '../redux/actions/auth';
import DropdownMenu from 'react-native-dropdown-menu';
import Icon from './Icon';

import async from '../dist/async';
import GoogleSpreadsheet from 'google-spreadsheet';

// spreadsheet key is the long id in the sheets URL
var doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet('my spreadsheet key');
var sheet;

async.series([
    function setAuth(step) {
        var creds_json = {
            client_email: 'my email',
            private_key: 'ridiculously long alphanumeric key'
        }

        doc.useServiceAccountAuth(creds, step);
    },
    function getInfoAndWorksheets(step) {
        doc.getInfo(function(err, info) {
            console.log('Loaded doc: '+info.title+' by '+info.author.email);
            sheet = info.worksheets[0];
            console.log('sheet 1: '+sheet.title+' '+sheet.rowCount+'x'+sheet.colCount);
            step();
        });
    },
    function workingWithRows(step) {
        // google provides some query options
        sheet.getRows({
            offset: 1,
            limit: 20,
            orderby: 'col2'
        }, function( err, rows ){
            console.log('Read '+rows.length+' rows');

            // the row is an object with keys set by the column headers
            rows[0].colname = 'new val';
            rows[0].save(); // this is async

            // deleting a row
            rows[0].del();  // this is async

            step();
        });
    },
    function workingWithCells(step) {
        sheet.getCells({
            'min-row': 1,
            'max-row': 5,
            'return-empty': true
        }, function(err, cells) {
            var cell = cells[0];
            console.log('Cell R'+cell.row+'C'+cell.col+' = '+cells.value);

            // cells have a value, numericValue, and formula
            // cell.value == '1'
            // cell.numericValue == 1;
            // cell.formula == '=ROW()';

            // updating `value` is "smart" and generally handles things for you
            cell.value = 123;
            cell.value = '=A1+B2'
            cell.save(); //async

            // bulk updates make it easy to update many cells at once
            cells[0].value = 1;
            cells[1].value = 2;
            cells[2].formula = '=A1+B1';
            sheet.bulkUpdateCells(cells); //async

            step();
        });
    },
    function managingSheets(step) {
        doc.addWorksheet({
            title: 'my new sheet'
        }, function(err, sheet) {

            // change a sheet's title
            sheet.setTitle('new title'); //async

            //resize a sheet
            sheet.resize({rowCount: 50, colCount: 20}); //async

            sheet.setHeaderRow(['name', 'age', 'phone']); //async

            // removing a worksheet
            sheet.del(); //async

            step();
        });
    }
]);

class Secured extends Component {
    render() {
        var data = [["Choice 1"], ["Choice 2"], ["Choice 3"], ["Choice 4"]];

        return(
            <ScrollView style={{padding: 20}}>
                <Icon/>

                <Text style={{fontSize: 27}}>
                    {`Welcome ${this.props.username}`}
                </Text>

                <View style={{flex: 1}}>

                    <DropdownMenu style={{flex: 1}}
                                  bgColor={"purple"}  //the background color of the head, default is grey
                                  tintColor={"white"} //the text color of the head, default is white
                                  selectItemColor={"orange"} //the text color of the selected item, default is red
                                  data={data}
                                  maxHeight={410}  // the max height of the menu
                                  handler={(selection, row) => alert(data[selection][row])} >

                        <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}} >
                        </View>
                    </DropdownMenu>

                </View>

                <View style={{margin: 20}}/>

                <Button onPress={(e) => this.userLogout(e)} title="Logout"/>

            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return {
        username: state.auth.username
    };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        onLogout: () => { dispatch(logout()); }
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Secured);
```